# VS2010 ignores "Add Service Reference"\"Collection Type"=List. Generates Arrays ONLY for Collections

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, webservice-client

Web service is located here: http://api.bing.net/search.wsdl

In VS2010's project I click "Add Service Reference". As "Collection Type" i specify "**System.Collections.Generic.List**" (or anything else in that list, but not Array). Click OK - it will generate code.

**Actual results**:

Code contains arrays instead of Lists:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=10)]
public SourceType[] Sources {
    get {
        return this.sourcesField;
    }
    set {
        this.sourcesField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Sources");
    }
}
```

**Expected results**:

Code should contain Lists for all collections.

**Question**:

There are bunch of files generated in web service folder that impact actual code generation:
Reference.svcmap, *.svcinfo, *.wsdl itself.

> **How can I force Wsdl2code generator (using these files mentioned above) to generate Lists for
>   this web service?**

Reference.svcmap contains lines to use lists, but it does not help:

```
<CollectionMappings>
  <CollectionMapping TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.List`1" Category="List" />
</CollectionMappings>
<GenerateSerializableTypes>true</GenerateSerializableTypes>
<Serializer>Auto</Serializer>
<UseSerializerForFaults>true</UseSerializerForFaults>
<ReferenceAllAssemblies>true</ReferenceAllAssemblies>
<ReferencedAssemblies />
<ReferencedDataContractTypes />
<ServiceContractMappings />
```

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159681) - but its best answer is not helpful for this situation.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.
Communications are based in SOAP 1.0 and SOAP 1.1 specifications (depending on the binding).
If you check http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/ you can't find lists, only arrays. 
In the posted example the list objects are serialized as arrays would be. To consume arrays as lists would probably require to implement a custom binding, witch is not a easy task. A simple solution is to wrap the proxy in a class.